# Why it is no use to set fileencoding=utf-8 in _vimrc?

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8

I want to save any file as utf-8 format when to input :wq .There is one line  in my _vimrc.

```
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

Now there is a file whose format is in cp936,it can be opened and all the chinese characters can be displayed correctly,many  times had tried ,it is no use for the config line `set fileencoding=utf-8` in my _vimrc.
1.to open a cp936 format file in gvim(win7)
2.to save it .
3.to reopen it in gvim.
4.in ex command ,:set fileencoding ,the result is cp936.

I have to set fileencoding in ex command .
1.to open a cp936 format file in gvim(win7)
2.in ex command ,:set fileencoding=utf-8
3.to save it .
4.to reopen it in gvim.
5.in ex command ,:set fileencoding ,the result is utf-8.

Why the `set fileencoding=utf-8 in _vimrc` do not work automatically?
How to change any cp936 file into utf-8 file automatically when to save it in gvim?How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `fileencoding` is set for each buffer Vim reads just after loading it.

> To read a file in a certain encoding it won't work by setting 'fileencoding' … If you prefer another encoding use an BufReadPost autocommand event to test if your preferred encoding is to be used.

`au BufReadPost * if &fileencoding == "cp936" | set fileencoding=utf-8 | endif`

See `:h 'fileencoding'` and `:h 'fileencodings'` (with 's' at the end) for details.